# How to take queuemanager backup and restored in linux

Tags: ibm-mq

Hello I have queue manager with name QM_1. Here I have taken backup of QM_1 like following.
after that I created queue manager(QM_1) with same name in other system and I need to restore the save qmgr properties. Pls provide how to restore the queuemanager properties?

```
saveqmgr -m QM_1 -f
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the options are are on the [SupportPac MS03](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS03) landing page.  (MS03 is the SupportPac that contains the `saveqmgr` program.)  Detailed instructions are in the download documentation.  The following instructions are copied from the SupportPac MS03 page:

---

You can run the following `saveqmgr` command (see below) to create 2 output files. Both output files are text and they can be edited.

- one with the object definitions (using option -f) - the file name in this example is: qmgr_data.mqsc
- the other with the authority records (using option -z which generates entries for setmqaut)
- the file name in this example is: qmgr_auth.bat (in Windows) or qmgr_auth.sh (in UNIX)

The following command saves both the objects and the authority records:

UNIX:

```
saveqmgr -m QMGR -f /tmp/mq/qmgr_data.mqsc -z /tmp/mq/qmgr_auth.sh
```

Windows:

```
saveqmgr.exe -m QMGR -f C:\temp\mq\qmgr_data.mqsc -z C:\temp\mq\qmgr_auth.bat
```

The file `qmgr_data.mqsc` can be run as follows when trying to restore the contents into a new queue manager:

```
runmqsc TEST < qmgr_data.mqsc
```

The file qmgr_auth.bat (in Windows) or qmgr_auth.sh (in UNIX) has stand-alone entries that invoke the setmqaut command with the proper parameter for each authority record. This batch/script file will need to be executed in order to restore the authority records.

UNIX:

```
chmod u+x qmgr_auth.sh
./qmgr_auth.sh
```

Windows:

```
qmgr_auth.bat
```

---

To find this and all the other SupportPacs, go to the SupportPac landing page [here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).

**Update 6 November 2014:**
Although OP asked *how to restore* from a `saveqmgr` backup, it is worth noting that IBM has provided the `dmpmqcfg` command beginning with version 7.1.  You can back up the QMgr in `MQSC` format using this syntax:

`dmpmqcfg -m [QUEUE_MANAGER] > BACKUP_FILE.mqsc`

This captures the object deinifions *and* the authorizations in a single file.  The authorizations are captured as `SET AUTHREC` entries rather than as `setmqaut` commands by default.

Please note that the initial versions of `dmpmqcfg` did not capture all of the authorization settings that you might have defined.  It is necessary for all versions to apply the latest Fix Pack to get a reliable backup using `dmpmqcfg`.  This behavior may regress in later Fix Packs so it is advisable to reconcile your backup against your auths creation script when switching to this command and after applying a Fix Pack.

Restore a QMGgr from the `dmpmqcfg` file the same as you would from the `saveqmgr` file:

`runmqsc [QMNAME] < output_of_dmpmqcfg_or_saveqmgr.mqsc > logfile.txt 2>&1`

This runs the `MQSC` file definitions into the QMgr (including `SET AUTHREC` commands) and saves the output of `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a log file.