# websphere mq Migration from 7.0.1.3 to 7.5.0.5 process

Tags: ibm-mq

currently we have using mq version 7.0.1.3 on Windows server(Fall Back server) and we have a plan to migrate mq 7.5.0.5 which is IBM supported version.

What are the steps should we follow for this activity?

How to take queue manager backup and restore the queue managers in latest version 7.5.0.5?

It is existing server
And some application having dependancy, 
Means we have to uninstall 7.0 version from the machine and install 7.5 and restore the queue managers in lattest mq 7.5 version

Kindly conform how should we take qmgr backup in version 7.0.K
means should we install MS03 packs in server.

I couldnt find the ms03 path kindly share the path for download MS03 supportpack.

1) I dont know how to take queue manager back up in version 7.0 .
Kindly help me For some points to take queue manager backup in 7.0 .

@Joshc;
i couldnt find any support pack from IBM pelase share the link for download MS03 support pack from IBM site.

@Joshc:
Thank you so much i have downloaded MS03 support pack and also i have done the migration from 7.0.1.3 to 7.5.0.5.

Comment: 7.5.0.8 is the latest in the 7.5 version of MQ.  Note that MQ v7.5 will go out of support on April 30th 2018, so you only have a little over 4 moths left before it too will be unsupported like 7.0 has been for over 2 years.  I would suggest you move directly to 9.0.0.2 since this will be supported until at least June 2021.

Comment: Are you planning to upgrade on the existing server or are you planning to install on a new server and migrate the queue manager over?

Comment: Do you want to onlytake a backup of the MQ configuration, or also of the messages?  MS03 will allow you to save off the MQ configuration, you also need the OAM rules, MS03 with the `-z` option will backup of the OAM rules.  You can also backup the queue manager name directories under the qmgrs and log sub directories the install path.  Note that you can perform an in place upgrade, no need to destroy the queue manager and restore it unless you have a issue, when you start the queue manager the first time after the upgrade it will migrate to the new version. Look at qload to save messages.

Comment: I can write up in a answer when I have more time.

Comment: You can always comment on your own post.  If you want to notify a specific person you commented just type @ followed by their name (ex: @JoshMc).  Did you google "MQ03 SupportPac"  it is fairly easy to find via google.  I have been off for many weeks at the end of the year and have not had much time to write up a detailed answer.

Comment: You might find this existing answer helpful as well: [How to take queuemanager backup and restored in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441102/how-to-take-queuemanager-backup-and-restored-in-linux/15454209#15454209) Note this does cover Windows as well.

Comment: Praveen in my comment on Jan 16 I provided a link to an answer which provided a direct link to the download page for MS03.  I also just googled the simple phrase "ms03 support pack download" and the first result is to the download page for this support pack.